# Python - Count number of times function passes through decorator

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, functools

I have a decorator that I wanna make increase a counter anytime a function is routed through the decorator. So far this is my code

```
from functools import wraps
def count_check(function):
    """Returns number of times any function with this decorator is called
    """
    count = []
    @wraps(function)
    def increase_count(*args, **kwargs):
        count.append(1)
        return function(*args, **kwargs), len(count)

    return increase_count
```

It works fine, until another function passes through the decorator and count resets to 0 for that function. How can I aggregate the total number of times?

Comment: Works for me. Please show the code that actually produces the bad behaviour.

Comment: Hello, there's no error, just unexpected behaviour. For example, if I decorate two functions with @count_check, they both have their own count, instead of totalling all counts.

Comment: You'd need a global count variable if you want a total for all calls to function decorated with @count_check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
from functools import wraps
def count_check(function, count=[0]):
    """Returns number of times any function with this decorator is called
    """
    @wraps(function)
    def increase_count(*args, **kwargs):
        count[0] += 1
        return function(*args, **kwargs), count[0]

    return increase_count
```

You could also get fancy and use a dictionary counting the functions individually as well as separately:

```
from functools import wraps
def count_check(function, count={}):
    """Returns number of times any function with this decorator is called
    """
    count[function] = 0
    @wraps(function)
    def increase_count(*args, **kwargs):
        count[function] += 1
        return function(*args, **kwargs), count[function], sum(count.values())

    return increase_count
```

Demo:

```
@count_check
def foo():
    return 42

print(foo(), foo(), foo())

@count_check
def bar():
    return 23

print(bar(), bar(), bar())
print(foo(), foo(), foo())
```

Prints:

```
(42, 1, 1) (42, 2, 2) (42, 3, 3)
(23, 1, 4) (23, 2, 5) (23, 3, 6)
(42, 4, 7) (42, 5, 8) (42, 6, 9)
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan, just what I needed.

Comment: Just learned something new.. Didn't realize python evaluated the default arguments only once and so returns the same mutable objects each time.. I like it.

Comment: I'm surprised myself. Didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like:

```
from functools import wraps
count = 0
def count_check(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def increase_count(*args, **kwargs):
        global count
        count += 1
        return function(*args, **kwargs), count

    return increase_count
```

Comment: Thanks junnytony, this did the trick. However, don't you think it's a bad idea to refer to count globally?

Comment: Generally I try to stay away from using global variables but if all count_check is doing is counting how many times all functions wrapped with it are called then it is fine since you're not keeping track of separate function calls.